# how to add new line at the end of file. using Only C

Tags: c

I am wondering how to add the new line before closing the file.

I have tried using `fputs` and `puts` and frpints something like `puts("/n");` etc 
but it doesnt work.

Thanks & regards,
SamPrat

Comment: Are you sure you didn't try `"\n"`?

Comment: i hve tried puts("/n") before fclose . but it appends /n at the end of the line

Comment: can you please post the full code? you wrote, `"/n"` which should be `"\n"

Comment: What I am trying to tell you is that it's not `/n` but `\n`.  With a backslash.

Comment: i will try that . and let u know

Comment: Guys that works, sorry to bother u guys , sily mistake from my side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a very simple way, no error checking:

```
FILE * file = fopen(fname, "a");
fwrite("\n", strlen("\n"), 1, file);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: hum, indeed. Just use strlen() instead of sizeof I guess

Answer (score 1):

You should use `"\n"` instead of `"/n"` with the file opened in "appending mode" (letter 'a' as fopen parameter

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with append flag "a" and then use fputs() function.

Answer (score 0):

The strings `"\n"` and `"/n"` are very different. The first has 1 character (plus a null terminator); the second has 2 characters (plus a null terminator).

The character used for line termination is `'\n'`. `puts()` appends one such character automatically.

The following statements do the same thing (they may return a different value, but that isn't used in the example below):

```
printf("full line\n");
fputs("full line\n", stdout);
puts("full line");
```